# Write a SQL query to return customers booked across multiple years but not booked in 2021

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to write a query to answer the following question:

"Provide a report of customers who have booked during 2018-2020 but not in 2021"

I've generated the following query to separate out the data by year shown below, each table represents customer bookings per year.

Get customer bookings by year:

```
with active_2018 as
(
    select c.id, c.email, c.telephone                       
    from customer c                     
    join booking b on b.customer_id = c.id                      
    where to_char(b.date_created, 'YYYY') = '2018'                      
    group by 1, 2, 3                    
),      
active_2019 as 
(
    select c.id, c.email, c.telephone                       
    from customer c                     
    join booking b on b.customer_id = c.id                      
    where to_char(b.date_created, 'YYYY') = '2019'                      
    group by 1, 2, 3                    
),  
active_2020 as 
(
    select c.id, c.email, c.telephone                       
    from customer c                     
    join booking b on b.customer_id = c.id                      
    where to_char(b.date_created, 'YYYY') = '2020'                      
    group by 1, 2, 3                    
),
active_2021 as 
(
    select c.id, c.email, c.telephone                       
    from customer c                     
    join booking b on b.customer_id = c.id                      
    where to_char(b.date_created, 'YYYY') = '2021'                      
    group by 1, 2, 3                    
)
```

I realise the following attempt is wrong but so far it's my best attempt, I think this query is saying show customer bookings who have booked in 2018 and 2019 and 2020 and not in 2021. This is wrong because I actually need customers who have booked in either 2018 or 2019 or 2020 but not in 2021.

Attempt #1 - failed:

```
select distinct(a.id), a.email, a.telephone     
from active_2018 a on a.id = a.id 
join active_2019 b on a.id = b.id   
join active_2020 c on a.id = c.id           
where a.id not in (select id from active_2021)
```

Answer (score 1):

*edit (again..]):* After comment below and looking at documentation. You actually need a union. Because they could be in 2018 or 2019 or 2020 but not 2021. The "or" is why I think you need a union not a join. Not someone who booked in every one of those years except 2021.

```
'
 select distinct(a.id) as id, a.email as email, a.telephone as telephone     
 from active_2018
 where a.id not in (select id from active_2021)
 union
 select distinct(b.id) as id, b.email as email, b.telephone as telephone     
 from active_2018 as b
 where b.id not in (select id from active_2021)
 union
 select distinct(c.id) as id, c.email as email, c.telephone as telephone     
 from active_2018 as c
 where c.id not in (select id from active_2021);               
 
'
```

Comment: Thanks Gregory, I was including active_2021 originally to check that they haven't booked in 2021.  Without that table the resultant data could include customers who have and haven't booked in 2021.  If the customer has booked in 2021 I don't want them included in the results

Comment: I have updated. Are you getting errors or just wrong data?

Comment: Also note that Union should provide distinct results natively, so my use of distinct is needles CPU usage. The query would be faster without distinct being selected.